Doubt on MODIFICATION of Multi Speed Rechargeable Fan & Multi Level Rechargeable Light
I have Solove F5 fan & Ulanzi VL49 light.
- Both are rechargeable & use 103450 3.7v lithium batteries
Rechargeable Batteries which came with both fan & light can't hold charge anymore.
- I don't want to replace the batteries
- Instead i want to connect these with PowerBank(PowerOutageScenario) or WallCharger(NormalScenario)
Solove F5 has three speeds.
My Doubt is - for each speed
- does the battery outputs increased/decreased Voltage? OR
- does the battery outputs increased/decreased Ampere? OR
- the battery gives same 3.7v & the circuit increases/decreases the voltage/ampere based on selected speed?
My Basic Question is:
- How these Rechargeable Devices with Multiple Levels operate electrically?
- Do they increase/decrease Level by increasing/decreasing the V to Motor/Light?
- Do they increase/decrease Level by increasing/decreasing the A(current) to Motor/Light?
